# JavaFX change the font color of text in a tab

Tags: java, css, javafx

I would like to dynamically change the color of the text in the tab label of a TabPane.

In SceneBuilder I've given the tab a name of randomTab.

In my code, I have the following:

```
    if (randomEnabled)
        randomTab.setStyle("-fx-color:Green;");
    else
        randomTab.setStyle("-fx-color:Black;");
```

However, this doesn't change the color of the text, it changes the color of the background of the tab's label.

I've tried "-fx-text-fill:Green" instead, as well as "-fx-foreground-color:Green", but neither of those have any effect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Labels inside the tab header, by default, use the "looked-up color" `-fx-text-base-color` defined in the default stylesheet modena.css. So a quick-and-dirty approach is just to override that color definition:

```
randomTab.setStyle("-fx-text-base-color: green;");
```

The problem with this approach is that anything else in the tab (i.e. not in the tab header) that uses `-fx-text-base-color` as its text fill will also change text color. Most controls actually use `-fx-text-background-color` as the text (foreground!) color, so you might get away with this simple approach. (Thanks to jewelsea, whose comments led me to the correct version of this approach.)

Probably a more robust approach is to define your own "looked-up color" for the text fill in the tab, and then change its value for a specific tab in code.

In your external CSS file, add

```css
.root {
    -tab-text-color: -fx-text-base-color ;
}

.tab-label {
    -fx-text-fill: -tab-text-color ;
}
```

Now to change the value of `-tab-text-color` for a specific tab, do

```
randomTab.setStyle("-tab-text-color: green;");
```

Here's a SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TabStyleTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        Tab tab1 = new Tab("Tab 1");
        tab1.setContent(new StackPane(new Label("Tab 1")));
        tab1.setStyle("-tab-text-color: green;");
        Tab tab2 = new Tab("Tab 2");
        tab2.setContent(new StackPane(new Label("Tab 2")));
        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab1, tab2);
        Scene scene = new Scene(tabPane, 600, 600) ;
        scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

where style.css is

```css
.root {
    -tab-text-color: -fx-text-base-color ;
}

.tab-label {
    -fx-text-fill: -tab-text-color ;
}
```

Giving

[image]

Comment: I think he wants to set the foreground color, not the background color, so perhaps `randomTab.setStyle("-fx-text-base-color: green ;");`, rather than `randomTab.setStyle("-fx-text-background-color: green ;");`.  Note that doing it code like this rather than a more specific selector in CSS will change the color of all text in the tab (not just the tab label header).

Comment: @jewelsea The (rather badly named) looked-up color `-fx-text-background-color` is used for the text fill over a region that uses `-fx-background` as its `background-color`; i.e. it is the text foreground color for certain controls (including labels). See the sections for `.root` and `.label` in [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/996511a322b7/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css).

Comment: Oh so it is, how confusing ;-)

Comment: @jewelsea Not exactly intuitively-named, is it...? Actually, just setting the `-fx-text-background-color` directly on a tab didn't seem to work anyway; not quite sure why. I removed that part from the answer.

Comment: @James_D thank you, that looks great.  However, when I add the .root clause to my application's CSS file, I get the warning "Unknown property: -tab-text-color".

Comment: @skrilmps You get that at runtime, or is it just your IDE complaining?

Comment: @James_D It's just the IDE complaining

Comment: @skrilmps So it's just that your IDE doesn't understand looked-up colors (basically, it's an IDE bug, as this is supported JavaFX CSS). You can ignore that warning ( or file a feature request with the authors of the IDE).

Answer (score 1):

Look, You can add this to your CSS file

```
.tab-label {
      -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
}
```